# how to edit a Sconstruct so that it rebuild the 'ext' folder

Tags: scons, canjs-construct

Here is a part of sconstruct file
Full: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/stable/SConstruct
The project: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/

```
# -*- mode:python -*-


########################################################################
#
# Set up the main build environment.
#
########################################################################

main = Environment(tools=[
        'default', 'git', TempFileSpawn, EnvDefaults, MakeActionTool,
        ConfigFile, AddLocalRPATH, SwitchingHeaders, TagImpliesTool, Blob
    ])

main.Tool(SCons.Tool.FindTool(['gcc', 'clang'], main))
main.Tool(SCons.Tool.FindTool(['g++', 'clang++'], main))

Export('main')

from gem5_scons.util import get_termcap
termcap = get_termcap()

# Check that we have a C/C++ compiler
if not ('CC' in main and 'CXX' in main):
    error("No C++ compiler installed (package g++ on Ubuntu and RedHat)")

# Find default configuration & binary.
Default(environ.get('M5_DEFAULT_BINARY', 'build/ARM/gem5.debug'))


########################################################################
#
# Figure out which configurations to set up based on the path(s) of
# the target(s).
#
########################################################################

# helper function: find last occurrence of element in list
def rfind(l, elt, offs = -1):
    for i in range(len(l)+offs, 0, -1):
        if l[i] == elt:
            return i
    raise ValueError("element not found")

# Take a list of paths (or SCons Nodes) and return a list with all
# paths made absolute and ~-expanded.  Paths will be interpreted
# relative to the launch directory unless a different root is provided
def makePathListAbsolute(path_list, root=GetLaunchDir()):
    return [abspath(os.path.join(root, expanduser(str(p))))
            for p in path_list]

# Each target must have 'build' in the interior of the path; the
# directory below this will determine the build parameters.  For
# example, for target 'foo/bar/build/X86/arch/x86/blah.do' we
# recognize that X86 specifies the configuration because it
# follow 'build' in the build path.

# The funky assignment to "[:]" is needed to replace the list contents
# in place rather than reassign the symbol to a new list, which
# doesn't work (obviously!).
BUILD_TARGETS[:] = makePathListAbsolute(BUILD_TARGETS)

# Generate a list of the unique build roots and configs that the
# collected targets reference.
variant_paths = set()
build_root = None
for t in BUILD_TARGETS:
    this_build_root, variant = parse_build_path(t)

    # Make sure all targets use the same build root.
    if not build_root:
        build_root = this_build_root
    elif this_build_root != build_root:
        error("build targets not under same build root\n  %s\n  %s" %
            (build_root, this_build_root))

    # Collect all the variants into a set.
    variant_paths.add(os.path.join('/', build_root, variant))

# Make sure build_root exists (might not if this is the first build there)
if not isdir(build_root):
    mkdir(build_root)
main['BUILDROOT'] = build_root


########################################################################
#
# Set up various paths.
#
########################################################################

base_dir = Dir('#src').abspath
Export('base_dir')

# the ext directory should be on the #includes path
main.Append(CPPPATH=[Dir('ext')])

# Add shared top-level headers
main.Prepend(CPPPATH=Dir('include'))
if not GetOption('duplicate_sources'):
    main.Prepend(CPPPATH=Dir('src'))


########################################################################
#
# Set command line options based on the configuration of the host and
# build settings.
#
########################################################################

# Initialize the Link-Time Optimization (LTO) flags
main['LTO_CCFLAGS'] = []
main['LTO_LINKFLAGS'] = []

# According to the readme, tcmalloc works best if the compiler doesn't
# assume that we're using the builtin malloc and friends. These flags
# are compiler-specific, so we need to set them after we detect which
# compiler we're using.
main['TCMALLOC_CCFLAGS'] = []

CXX_version = readCommand([main['CXX'], '--version'], exception=False)

main['GCC'] = CXX_version and CXX_version.find('g++') >= 0
main['CLANG'] = CXX_version and CXX_version.find('clang') >= 0
if main['GCC'] + main['CLANG'] > 1:
    error('Two compilers enabled at once?')

# Find the gem5 binary target architecture (usually host architecture). The
# "Target: <target>" is consistent accross gcc and clang at the time of
# writting this.
bin_target_arch = readCommand([main['CXX'], '--verbose'], exception=False)
main["BIN_TARGET_ARCH"] = (
    "x86_64"
    if bin_target_arch.find("Target: x86_64") != -1
    else "aarch64"
    if bin_target_arch.find("Target: aarch64") != -1
    else "unknown"
)

########################################################################
#
# Detect and configure external dependencies.
#
########################################################################

main['USE_PYTHON'] = not GetOption('without_python')

def config_embedded_python(env):
    # Find Python include and library directories for embedding the
    # interpreter. We rely on python-config to resolve the appropriate
    # includes and linker flags. If you want to link in an alternate version
    # of python, override the PYTHON_CONFIG variable.

    python_config = env.Detect(env['PYTHON_CONFIG'])
    if python_config is None:
        error("Can't find a suitable python-config, tried "
              f"{env['PYTHON_CONFIG']}")

    print(f"Info: Using Python config: {python_config}")

    cmd = [python_config, '--ldflags', '--includes']

    # Starting in Python 3.8 the --embed flag is required. Use it if supported.
    with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
        if conf.TryAction(f'@{python_config} --embed')[0]:
            cmd.append('--embed')

    def flag_filter(env, cmd_output, unique=True):
        # Since this function does not use the `unique` param, one should not
        # pass any value to this param.
        assert(unique==True)
        flags = cmd_output.split()
        prefixes = ('-l', '-L', '-I')
        is_useful = lambda x: any(x.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes)
        useful_flags = list(filter(is_useful, flags))
        env.MergeFlags(' '.join(useful_flags))

    env.ParseConfig(cmd, flag_filter)

    env.Prepend(CPPPATH=Dir('ext/pybind11/include/'))

    with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
        # verify that this stuff works
        if not conf.CheckHeader('Python.h', '<>'):
            error("Check failed for Python.h header.\n",
                  "Two possible reasons:\n"
                  "1. Python headers are not installed (You can install the "
                  "package python-dev on Ubuntu and RedHat)\n"
                  "2. SCons is using a wrong C compiler. This can happen if "
                  "CC has the wrong value.\n"
                  f"CC = {env['CC']}")
        py_version = conf.CheckPythonLib()
        if not py_version:
            error("Can't find a working Python installation")

    # Found a working Python installation. Check if it meets minimum
    # requirements.
    ver_string = '.'.join(map(str, py_version))
    if py_version[0] < 3 or (py_version[0] == 3 and py_version[1] < 6):
        error('Embedded python library 3.6 or newer required, found '
              f'{ver_string}.')
    elif py_version[0] > 3:
        warning('Embedded python library too new. '
                f'Python 3 expected, found {ver_string}.')


########################################################################
#
# Define build environments for required variants.
#
########################################################################

for variant_path in variant_paths:
    # Make a copy of the build-root environment to use for this config.
    env = main.Clone()
    env['BUILDDIR'] = variant_path

    gem5_build = os.path.join(build_root, variant_path, 'gem5.build')
    env['GEM5BUILD'] = gem5_build
    Execute(Mkdir(gem5_build))

    env.SConsignFile(os.path.join(gem5_build, 'sconsign'))

    # Set up default C++ compiler flags
    if env['GCC'] or env['CLANG']:
        # As gcc and clang share many flags, do the common parts here
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-pipe'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fno-strict-aliasing'])

        # Enable -Wall and -Wextra and then disable the few warnings that
        # we consistently violate
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-Wall', '-Wundef', '-Wextra',
                            '-Wno-sign-compare', '-Wno-unused-parameter'])

        # We always compile using C++17
        env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17'])

        if sys.platform.startswith('freebsd'):
            env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-I/usr/local/include'])
            env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-I/usr/local/include'])
            # On FreeBSD we need libthr.
            env.Append(LIBS=['thr'])

        with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
            conf.CheckLinkFlag('-Wl,--as-needed')

        linker = GetOption('linker')
        if linker:
            with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
                if not conf.CheckLinkFlag(f'-fuse-ld={linker}'):
                    # check mold support for gcc older than 12.1.0
                    if linker == 'mold' and \
                       (env['GCC'] and \
                           compareVersions(env['CXXVERSION'],
                                           "12.1.0") < 0) and \
                       ((isdir('/usr/libexec/mold') and \
                           conf.CheckLinkFlag('-B/usr/libexec/mold')) or \
                       (isdir('/usr/local/libexec/mold') and \
                           conf.CheckLinkFlag('-B/usr/local/libexec/mold'))):
                        pass # support mold
                    else:
                        error(f'Linker "{linker}" is not supported')
                if linker == 'gold' and not GetOption('with_lto'):
                    # Tell the gold linker to use threads. The gold linker
                    # segfaults if both threads and LTO are enabled.
                    conf.CheckLinkFlag('-Wl,--threads')
                    conf.CheckLinkFlag(
                            '-Wl,--thread-count=%d' % GetOption('num_jobs'))


    else:
        error('\n'.join((
              "Don't know what compiler options to use for your compiler.",
              "compiler: " + env['CXX'],
              "version: " + CXX_version.replace('\n', '<nl>') if
                    CXX_version else 'COMMAND NOT FOUND!',
              "If you're trying to use a compiler other than GCC",
              "or clang, there appears to be something wrong with your",
              "environment.",
              "",
              "If you are trying to use a compiler other than those listed",
              "above you will need to ease fix SConstruct and ",
              "src/SConscript to support that compiler.")))

    if env['GCC']:
        if compareVersions(env['CXXVERSION'], "7") < 0:
            error('gcc version 7 or newer required.\n'
                  'Installed version:', env['CXXVERSION'])

        # Add the appropriate Link-Time Optimization (LTO) flags if
        # `--with-lto` is set.
        if GetOption('with_lto'):
            # g++ uses "make" to parallelize LTO. The program can be overriden
            # with the environment variable "MAKE", but we currently make no
            # attempt to plumb that variable through.
            parallelism = ''
            if env.Detect('make'):
                parallelism = '=%d' % GetOption('num_jobs')
            else:
                warning('"make" not found, link time optimization will be '
                        'single threaded.')

            for var in 'LTO_CCFLAGS', 'LTO_LINKFLAGS':
                # Use the same amount of jobs for LTO as scons.
                env[var] = ['-flto%s' % parallelism]

        env.Append(TCMALLOC_CCFLAGS=[
            '-fno-builtin-malloc', '-fno-builtin-calloc',
            '-fno-builtin-realloc', '-fno-builtin-free'])

        if compareVersions(env['CXXVERSION'], "9") < 0:
            # `libstdc++fs`` must be explicitly linked for `std::filesystem``
            # in GCC version 8. As of GCC version 9, this is not required.
            #
            # In GCC 7 the `libstdc++fs`` library explicit linkage is also
            # required but the `std::filesystem` is under the `experimental`
            # namespace(`std::experimental::filesystem`).
            #
            # Note: gem5 does not support GCC versions < 7.
            env.Append(LIBS=['stdc++fs'])

    elif env['CLANG']:
        if compareVersions(env['CXXVERSION'], "6") < 0:
            error('clang version 6 or newer required.\n'
                  'Installed version:', env['CXXVERSION'])

        # Set the Link-Time Optimization (LTO) flags if enabled.
        if GetOption('with_lto'):
            for var in 'LTO_CCFLAGS', 'LTO_LINKFLAGS':
                env[var] = ['-flto']

        # clang has a few additional warnings that we disable.
        with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
            conf.CheckCxxFlag('-Wno-c99-designator')
            conf.CheckCxxFlag('-Wno-defaulted-function-deleted')

        env.Append(TCMALLOC_CCFLAGS=['-fno-builtin'])

        if compareVersions(env['CXXVERSION'], "11") < 0:
            # `libstdc++fs`` must be explicitly linked for `std::filesystem``
            # in clang versions 6 through 10.
            #
            # In addition, for these versions, the
            # `std::filesystem` is under the `experimental`
            # namespace(`std::experimental::filesystem`).
            #
            # Note: gem5 does not support clang versions < 6.
            env.Append(LIBS=['stdc++fs'])


        # On Mac OS X/Darwin we need to also use libc++ (part of XCode) as
        # opposed to libstdc++, as the later is dated.
        if sys.platform == "darwin":
            env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-stdlib=libc++'])
            env.Append(LIBS=['c++'])

    # Add sanitizers flags
    sanitizers=[]
    if GetOption('with_ubsan'):
        sanitizers.append('undefined')
    if GetOption('with_asan'):
        # Available for gcc >= 5 or llvm >= 3.1 both a requirement
        # by the build system
        sanitizers.append('address')
        suppressions_file = Dir('util').File('lsan-suppressions').get_abspath()
        suppressions_opt = 'suppressions=%s' % suppressions_file
        suppressions_opts = ':'.join([suppressions_opt,
                                      'print_suppressions=0'])
        env['ENV']['LSAN_OPTIONS'] = suppressions_opts
        print()
        warning('To suppress false positive leaks, set the LSAN_OPTIONS '
                'environment variable to "%s" when running gem5' %
                suppressions_opts)
        warning('LSAN_OPTIONS=%s' % suppressions_opts)
        print()
    if sanitizers:
        sanitizers = ','.join(sanitizers)
        if env['GCC'] or env['CLANG']:
            env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fsanitize=%s' % sanitizers,
                                 '-fno-omit-frame-pointer'],
                        LINKFLAGS=['-fsanitize=%s' % sanitizers,
                                   '-static-libasan'])

            if main["BIN_TARGET_ARCH"] == "x86_64":
                # Sanitizers can enlarge binary size drammatically, north of
                # 2GB.  This can prevent successful linkage due to symbol
                # relocation outside from the 2GB region allocated by the small
                # x86_64 code model that is enabled by default (32-bit relative
                # offset limitation).  Switching to the medium model in x86_64
                # enables 64-bit relative offset for large objects (>64KB by
                # default) while sticking to 32-bit relative addressing for
                # code and smaller objects. Note this comes at a potential
                # performance cost so it should not be enabled in all cases.
                # This should still be a very happy medium for
                # non-perf-critical sanitized builds.
                env.Append(CCFLAGS='-mcmodel=medium')
                env.Append(LINKFLAGS='-mcmodel=medium')
            elif main["BIN_TARGET_ARCH"] == "aarch64":
                # aarch64 default code model is small but with different
                # constrains than for x86_64. With aarch64, the small code
                # model enables 4GB distance between symbols. This is
                # sufficient for the largest ALL/gem5.debug target with all
                # sanitizers enabled at the time of writting this. Note that
                # the next aarch64 code model is "large" which prevents dynamic
                # linkage so it should be avoided when possible.
                pass
            else:
                warning(
                    "Unknown code model options for your architecture. "
                    "Linkage might fail for larger binaries "
                    "(e.g., ALL/gem5.debug with sanitizers enabled)."
                )
        else:
            warning("Don't know how to enable %s sanitizer(s) for your "
                    "compiler." % sanitizers)

    if sys.platform == 'cygwin':
        # cygwin has some header file issues...
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-Wno-uninitialized"])


    if not GetOption('no_compress_debug'):
        with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
            if not conf.CheckCxxFlag('-gz'):
                warning("Can't enable object file debug section compression")
            if not conf.CheckLinkFlag('-gz'):
                warning("Can't enable executable debug section compression")

    if env['USE_PYTHON']:
        config_embedded_python(env)
        gem5py_env = env.Clone()
    else:
        gem5py_env = env.Clone()
        config_embedded_python(gem5py_env)

    # Bare minimum environment that only includes python
    gem5py_env.Append(CCFLAGS=['${GEM5PY_CCFLAGS_EXTRA}'])
    gem5py_env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['${GEM5PY_LINKFLAGS_EXTRA}'])

    if GetOption('gprof') and GetOption('pprof'):
        error('Only one type of profiling should be enabled at a time')
    if GetOption('gprof'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g', '-pg'], LINKFLAGS=['-pg'])
    if GetOption('pprof'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g'],
                LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,--no-as-needed', '-lprofiler',
                    '-Wl,--as-needed'])

    env['HAVE_PKG_CONFIG'] = env.Detect('pkg-config')

    with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
        # On Solaris you need to use libsocket for socket ops
        if not conf.CheckLibWithHeader(
                [None, 'socket'], 'sys/socket.h', 'C++', 'accept(0,0,0);'):
           error("Can't find library with socket calls (e.g. accept()).")

        if not conf.CheckLibWithHeader('z', 'zlib.h', 'C++','zlibVersion();'):
            error('Did not find needed zlib compression library '
                  'and/or zlib.h header file.\n'
                  'Please install zlib and try again.')

    if not GetOption('without_tcmalloc'):
        with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:
            if conf.CheckLib('tcmalloc_minimal'):
                conf.env.Append(CCFLAGS=conf.env['TCMALLOC_CCFLAGS'])
            elif conf.CheckLib('tcmalloc'):
                conf.env.Append(CCFLAGS=conf.env['TCMALLOC_CCFLAGS'])
            else:
                warning("You can get a 12% performance improvement by "
                        "installing tcmalloc (libgoogle-perftools-dev package "
                        "on Ubuntu or RedHat).")

    if not GetOption('silent'):
        print("Building in", variant_path)

    # variant_dir is the tail component of build path, and is used to
    # determine the build parameters (e.g., 'X86')
    (build_root, variant_dir) = os.path.split(variant_path)


    # Register a callback to call after all SConsopts files have been read.
    after_sconsopts_callbacks = []
    def AfterSConsopts(cb):
        after_sconsopts_callbacks.append(cb)
    Export('AfterSConsopts')

    # Sticky variables get saved in the variables file so they persist from
    # one invocation to the next (unless overridden, in which case the new
    # value becomes sticky).
    sticky_vars = Variables(args=ARGUMENTS)
    Export('sticky_vars')

    # EXTRAS is special since it affects what SConsopts need to be read.
    sticky_vars.Add(('EXTRAS', 'Add extra directories to the compilation', ''))

    # Set env variables according to the build directory config.
    sticky_vars.files = []
    # Variables for $BUILD_ROOT/$VARIANT_DIR are stored in
    # $BUILD_ROOT/$VARIANT_DIR/gem5.build/variables

    gem5_build_vars = os.path.join(gem5_build, 'variables')
    build_root_vars = os.path.join(build_root, 'variables', variant_dir)
    current_vars_files = [gem5_build_vars, build_root_vars]
    existing_vars_files = list(filter(isfile, current_vars_files))
    if existing_vars_files:
        sticky_vars.files.extend(existing_vars_files)
        if not GetOption('silent'):
            print('Using saved variables file(s) %s' %
                    ', '.join(existing_vars_files))
    else:
        # Variant specific variables file doesn't exist.

        # Get default build variables from source tree.  Variables are
        # normally determined by name of $VARIANT_DIR, but can be
        # overridden by '--default=' arg on command line.
        default = GetOption('default')
        opts_dir = Dir('#build_opts').abspath
        if default:
            default_vars_files = [
                    gem5_build_vars,
                    build_root_vars,
                    os.path.join(opts_dir, default)
                ]
        else:
            default_vars_files = [os.path.join(opts_dir, variant_dir)]
        existing_default_files = list(filter(isfile, default_vars_files))
        if existing_default_files:
            default_vars_file = existing_default_files[0]
            sticky_vars.files.append(default_vars_file)
            print("Variables file(s) %s not found,\n  using defaults in %s" %
                    (' or '.join(current_vars_files), default_vars_file))
        else:
            error("Cannot find variables file(s) %s or default file(s) %s" %
                    (' or '.join(current_vars_files),
                     ' or '.join(default_vars_files)))
            Exit(1)

    # Apply current settings for EXTRAS to env.
    sticky_vars.Update(env)

    # Parse EXTRAS variable to build list of all directories where we're
    # look for sources etc.  This list is exported as extras_dir_list.
    if env['EXTRAS']:
        extras_dir_list = makePathListAbsolute(env['EXTRAS'].split(':'))
    else:
        extras_dir_list = []

    Export('extras_dir_list')

    # Variables which were determined with Configure.
    env['CONF'] = {}

    # Walk the tree and execute all SConsopts scripts that wil add to the
    # above variables
    if GetOption('verbose'):
        print("Reading SConsopts")

    def trySConsopts(dir):
        sconsopts_path = os.path.join(dir, 'SConsopts')
        if not isfile(sconsopts_path):
            return
        if GetOption('verbose'):
            print("Reading", sconsopts_path)
        SConscript(sconsopts_path, exports={'main': env})

    trySConsopts(Dir('#').abspath)
    for bdir in [ base_dir ] + extras_dir_list:
        if not isdir(bdir):
            error("Directory '%s' does not exist." % bdir)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(bdir):
            trySConsopts(root)

    # Call any callbacks which the SConsopts files registered.
    for cb in after_sconsopts_callbacks:
        cb()

    # Update env for new variables added by the SConsopts.
    sticky_vars.Update(env)

    Help('''
Build variables for {dir}:
{help}
'''.format(dir=variant_dir, help=sticky_vars.GenerateHelpText(env)),
         append=True)

    # If the old vars file exists, delete it to avoid confusion/stale values.
    if isfile(build_root_vars):
        warning(f'Deleting old variant variables file "{build_root_vars}"')
        remove(build_root_vars)
    # Save sticky variables back to the gem5.build variant variables file.
    sticky_vars.Save(gem5_build_vars, env)

    # Pull all the sticky variables into the CONF dict.
    env['CONF'].update({key: env[key] for key in sticky_vars.keys()})

    # Do this after we save setting back, or else we'll tack on an
    # extra 'qdo' every time we run scons.
    if env['CONF']['BATCH']:
        env['CC']     = env['CONF']['BATCH_CMD'] + ' ' + env['CC']
        env['CXX']    = env['CONF']['BATCH_CMD'] + ' ' + env['CXX']
        env['AS']     = env['CONF']['BATCH_CMD'] + ' ' + env['AS']
        env['AR']     = env['CONF']['BATCH_CMD'] + ' ' + env['AR']
        env['RANLIB'] = env['CONF']['BATCH_CMD'] + ' ' + env['RANLIB']

    # Cache build files in the supplied directory.
    if env['CONF']['M5_BUILD_CACHE']:
        print('Using build cache located at', env['CONF']['M5_BUILD_CACHE'])
        CacheDir(env['CONF']['M5_BUILD_CACHE'])


    env.Append(CCFLAGS='$CCFLAGS_EXTRA')
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS='$LINKFLAGS_EXTRA')

    exports=['env', 'gem5py_env']

    ext_dir = Dir('#ext').abspath
    variant_ext = os.path.join(variant_path, 'ext')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ext_dir):
        if 'SConscript' in files:
            build_dir = os.path.relpath(root, ext_dir)
            SConscript(os.path.join(root, 'SConscript'),
                       variant_dir=os.path.join(variant_ext, build_dir),
                       exports=exports,
                       duplicate=GetOption('duplicate_sources'))

    # The src/SConscript file sets up the build rules in 'env' according
    # to the configured variables.  It returns a list of environments,
    # one for each variant build (debug, opt, etc.)
    SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir=variant_path, exports=exports,
               duplicate=GetOption('duplicate_sources'))

atexit.register(summarize_warnings)
```

I have changed some code in the .cc .h files that are in the **ext** folder.
If the build is done for the first time, then these changes are visible to scons.
But if build already exists, then scons ignores the changes.
If you change the code in the **src** directory, scons will see them.

Comment: That's a lot to try to look at. The question is how the external libs are set up to relate to the project - whether they are fully integrated in the build or not (which is a tricky question for any build setup, SCons or not). The behavior you're reporting sounds like the SCons Requires behavior (https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-Requires) - is that method being used in the setup?

Comment: Which specific files in the ext dir have you changed?

Comment: What was the full command line you used to run scons with all the command line arguments? Which version of SCons, python, which OS?